# No main manifest attribute in jar file error in maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I'm currently building a discord bot in java but when i try to export the .jar file and run it it gives the following error: "no main manifest attribute, in name.jar"
I followed what many answers told to fix the problem tweaking the pom.xml file but it still has this problem.
My pom file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.furetto126.furettobot.FurettoBot</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.furetto126.furettobot</groupId>
    <artifactId>FurettoBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>dv8tion</id>
            <name>m2-dv8tion</name>
            <url>https://m2.dv8tion.net/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sedmelluq</groupId>
            <artifactId>lavaplayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.77</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm quite new to using maven so the problem might be obvious but i couldn't find any solution online

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried code below?

```
<plugin>
  <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
        <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: added it to my pom.xml but still doesn't work D: